# Getting a list of contracts using cleos to identify air drops

Tags: cleos, airdrops, contract-name

I want to automate finding out if an account has received an airdrop. So far what I came up with:

1. Find a list of all contracts (exclude the system contracts such as eos.tokens, eos.names, eos.ram, etc.)
2. Run cleos to query the contract for the accounts using the scope (particular account)

Example:

$ cleos -u http://api.eosnewyork.io get table eosdactokens dummyaccount accounts

How can I get a list of all the contracts created by air drops.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can ask cleos directly for that information.  I think you need to inspect the contracts that get uploaded yourself to identify them.  That could be automated, of course.

Comment: How do I inspect the contracts that get uploaded?

Comment: perhaps start with something like this:

cleos get abi eosdactokens

Comment: The issue is I don't know the names of the contracts.

Comment: Yes as far as I know the only way to detect them is to crawl the blocks and look for calls to issue() or other related tx that indicate a new token.

Answer (score 0):

You can now use https://www.eossnapshots.io/ to get a list of accounts updated daily if you don't want to download the ledger yourself